# Django query WHERE 1 IN (column1, column2)

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-queryset

In PostgreSQL this query is valid and yield the correct result

```
SELECT ID FROM table WHERE 1 in (column1, column2);
```

The result is  `0,2` given the following table

```
+----+---------+---------+
| ID | column1 | column2 |
+----+---------+---------+
| 0  |    1    |    0    |
+----+---------+---------+
| 1  |    2    |    3    |
+----+---------+---------+
| 2  |    2    |    1    |
+----+---------+---------+
| 3  |    0    |    4    |
+----+---------+---------+
```

How can I model it in Django ORM?

I thought about custom lookups, but I would need `'1__myin' = [column1, column2]` which produces `Cannot resolve keyword '1' into field.`
I'd like to avoid RAW SQL as I would like not to put some vulnerabilities in my code by mistake.

On the same row, all column_x have different values

Answer (score 2):

Try using [`Q`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q) and just check against each column

```
from django.db.models import Q

MyModel.objects.filter(Q(column1=1) | Q(column2=2))
```

Which will case sql something like

```
SELECT * FROM sometable WHERE column1=1 OR column2=1
```

Comment: I have 5 columns like that and I'd like to match up to 4 values against them. That means 20 ANDs/ORs, while with the IN i get just 4 ANDs. Isn't there a way to flip the IN clause?

Comment: `values = [1,2,3,4]`, `.filter(Q(column1__in=values) | Q(column2__in=values) | ...)` ?

Comment: That returns any row in which at least a column is in values, doesn't it?
I want to return every row in which 4 columns are equal to values, and one is whatever.
With values = [1,2,3,4] I want columns which are whatever permutation of [1,2,3,4,X]

Comment: That should have been your question then :P
If all the columns are different (as mentioned in your question) then just use `&` instead of `|`.

Comment: You are right. Sorry, I have a hard time expressing the concept :) I hoped the code could express it. I can't use just 5 & because one column will not be in the value. So I need to make 5 OR where inside I have 4 AND where I check column[1,2,3,4], column[1,2,3,5], column[1,2,4,5], column[1,3,4,5], column[2,3,4,5].
If I need 3 values, the combinations increase even more..

Answer (score 0):

I ended up implementing a custom filter to make this "reverse IN", so that you can query the columns instead of the values.

The filter works like this

`col_name_1__revin=[value, 'col_name_2', 'col_name_3']`

and it generates

`value IN ("table_name"."col_name_1", "table_name"."col_name_2", "table_name"."col_name_3")`

Only tested on `IntegerField` but should work with the other fields too, as long as you provide the correct value type.

```
from django.db.models import lookups
import re

class ReverseIn(lookups.In):
    lookup_name = 'revin'

    def get_prep_lookup(self):
        # We will always call this on a ChampionIntegerField with lookup_name = revin
        if not hasattr(self.rhs, '__iter__'):
            raise ValueError('ReverseIn only works with iterables. Got {} of type {}.'.format(self.rhs),type(self.rhs))
        self.table_name = self.lhs.field.model._meta.db_table
        self.output_field = self.lhs.output_field
        rhs = list(self.rhs)
        lhs = self.lhs.field.column
        try:
            self.lhs = self.lhs.output_field.get_prep_lookup("exact", rhs[0])
        except (TypeError, ValueError) as e:
            raise ValueError('The type of the first item of the argument must be compatible with the type of the column', e)
        return [lhs] + rhs[1:]

    def process_rhs(self, compiler, connection):
        if self.rhs_is_direct_value():
            # Do the quoting yourself, as Django outputs ' instead of " for parameters, and PostgreSQL complains
            # THIS IS DANGEROUS!!!!! I wish I could do it with parameters...
            def sql_sanitize(value):
                # Check if the value respects the rules for column names
                if re.match(r'^[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*', value):
                    return value
                else:
                    raise ValueError("The argument {} is not a valid column name".format(value))

            sql = ", ".join('"{}"."{}"'.format(self.table_name, sql_sanitize(value)) for value in set(self.rhs))
            params = []
            return sql, params
        else:
            raise NotImplementedError("ReverseIn only supports direct values")

    def as_sql(self, compiler, connection):
        rhs, rhs_params = self.process_rhs(compiler, connection)
        sql = "%s IN ({rhs})".format(rhs=rhs)
        params = [self.lhs]
        params.extend(rhs_params)
        return sql, params

IntegerField.register_lookup(ReverseIn)
```